# How to animate CardView?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have RecyclerView with CardView elements. I want to tap some of this CardView`s and other Cards slide down. How do you think, which methods or libs I should use? Link pls some tutorial that may help with my problem. There are pictures what I mean:
[1st screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTviI.png)

[2nd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDvej.png)

Comment: See this: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: @MicheleLacorte How do you think, Can I use this lib in my commerical projects or better way is create my own method?

Comment: It depends on what purpose you have and how much time you have, if you have to recreate everything from 0 may lose a lot of time , however the library is complete , up to you